# how to query data inside nested data in flask_sqlalchemy

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, marshmallow

i using flask_marshmallow here to show out my json response to frontend,

i have i table like bellow

```
class PostImgList(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'boat_img_list'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    link = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    main = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    boat_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("boat.id"))

class Post(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'boat'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(200))
    seat_capacity = db.Column(db.Integer)
    img_list = db.relationship(PostImgList, backref='boat', lazy=True)
```

i can get whole my data with :

```
class PostImgListSchema(ma.ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = PostImgList

class PostSchemaClass(ma.Schema):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'seat_capacity', 'img_list')
    img_list = ma.Nested(PostImgListSchema, many=True, only='link')


schema = PostSchemaClass(many=True)

data = Post.query.all()
data = schema.dump(data).data
return data
```

and frontend can get the data like below

```
"data": [
    {
      "seat_capacity": 1,
      "id": 1,
      "name": "mantapt",
      "img_list": [
        "fffadweda",
        "fffadweda",
        "fffadweda",
        "fffadweda",
        "fffadweda"
      ]
    },
    {
      "seat_capacity": 10,
      "id": 2,
      "name": "keren",
      "img_list": [
        "fffadweda"
      ]
    }
  ]
```

i know it's set with `many=True` in `PostImgListSchema`, i just wanna some data of that nested schema with a query filter in just one result, so i have to set  `many=False` for `PostImgListSchema` ?
so, how to write `PostImgListSchema` schema ?

i just wanna show out where of my `PostImgList` with filter `main field value` that is `True`,  simply it's similar like bellow :

```
"data": [
    {
      "seat_capacity": 1,
      "id": 1,
      "name": "mantapt",
      "img_list": "fffadweda"
    },
    {
      "seat_capacity": 10,
      "id": 2,
      "name": "keren",
      "img_list": "fffadweda"
    }
  ]
```

thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using primaryjoin or secondaryjoin (to specify your join condition) in combination with uselist=False should do the trick (see [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship) for details).

Comment: if i do that, i can't filter my `PostImgList`

Comment: Why can't you? You can include it in join condition.

Answer (score 0):

solved !!!

i just create a protperty in class model `Post`

```
class Post(db.Model):
...
...
    @property
    def image(self):
        img = PostImgList.query.filter_by(main=True).first()
        if not img:
            return ""
        return img.link
```

Comment: Be aware that this property will be recomputed every time you access it and it is read-only.

Comment: Thanks @MikhailBerlinkov,  now I just realized